# How do characters gain XP when I'm not playing as them?

Tags: river-city-girls-2

I've been playing River City Girls 2 in 3-player co-op. The characters we've been playing as, (Misako, Kyoko, Riki), are all level 30. The characters we haven't touched (Kunio, Marian, Provide) are level 19.

How did characters we haven't played as gain experience and level up? What determines how much XP they get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe all party members get XP when completing missions even if they aren't in your party. By contrast, XP from defeating enemies is not shared.